# Xming and Cygwin/X

Tags: x11-forwarding, xming, cygwin-x

For the sole purpose of remotely accessing X applications on Linux from a Windows machine:

- What are the differences between [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) and [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/)? (e.g. in terms of speed/features). Do they satisfy the same needs?

Also, there seem to be two separate "branches" of Xming

- The Xming **public release** 6.9.03, that was released in 2007 (5 years ago)
- The more recent **stable release** (for donors only), last updated in July, 2012

What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

I think Cygwin/X and Xming used to share the same code base. However, each one started their own improvements once they are separated.

The difference between 2007 and 2012 versions must be obvious.

I suggest Cygwin/X over Xming as Xming is not free and not configurable.

Comment: Thanks ernesto. When you say `the difference between 2007 and 2012 versions must be obvious` what do you mean?

Comment: I mean development on 2007 version is halted. No more bug fixes/enhancements for that version. Whereas the latest version will have all latest code, fixes and tested properly on latest platform such as windows 7.